# Site cannot be reached with Nginx ,Gunicorn , django on aws ec2

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I have followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04 to setup my Django app on **ec2** but it is not accessible.  When I hit the url it says that site cannot be reached.
I did ssh to my **ec2** instance and uses the curl command it shows me the html page but without it says connection cannot be established curl output:

[image]

Security Groups are also configured with port 80 and 443:
[image]

Also I set firewall to 'Nginx Full' - local firewall configuration:
[image]

When I run the command **sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket** it shows:
[image]

The command **sudo systemctl status gunicorn** shows:
[image]

Also the command **sudo systemctl status nginx** shows:
[image]

Comment: Without knowing anything, is Security group configured to pass traffic on relevant ports (80, 443 etc.)?

Comment: I updated my question  now you can check.